# Doing task that takes time without slow Web browsing on my WebView - parallel action

Tags: android, parallel-processing, android-webview

I want a user browses the Internet and scrolls the site down / up while I download images from the internet without the user knowledge  - the action of downloading images will not slow the application - Now it looks like the web page froze for several seconds. 
After downloading the images I show message with ViewFlipper.
How can I fulfilling this?

Thank's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to do something like updating UI thread while doing some downloading image process in background then you should use AsyncTask

a complete refrence to AsyncTask can be found here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: There are slow loading web page.
At the same time I surf in a web page with webView and I upload pictures in doInBackground. 
I feel slow web page scrolling.
Do you know why this happens?
Thank you.

Comment: i have no clear idea but i hope this link may help you http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/119213/android-scroll-laggs-and-page-loads-very-slow-with-example